# Docker Is supposed to be listening but it doesn't

Tags: docker

I deployed my first scala project on docker but i have a problem, the problem is the docker says that the server has been started, but surprisingly it doesn't listen to any request, even i exposed the port to the host, when i tried to request a get, it says that the connection is refused, also i tried to telnet to the port and it seems that there are no listener on port 9000 neither 3200 an 3000, please find bellow what i have wrote in dockerFile

```
FROM jelastic/sbt
# Env variables
ENV SCALA_VERSION 2.12.4
ENV SBT_VERSION 1.1.0

# Scala expects this file
RUN touch /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/release

# Install Scala
## Piping curl directly in tar
RUN \
  curl -fsL https://downloads.typesafe.com/scala/$SCALA_VERSION/scala-$SCALA_VERSION.tgz | tar xfz - -C /root/ && \
  echo >> /root/.bashrc && \
  echo "export PATH=~/scala-$SCALA_VERSION/bin:$PATH" >> /root/.bashrc

# Install sbt
RUN \
  curl -L -o sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian/sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb && \
  dpkg -i sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb && \
  rm sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install sbt && \
  sbt sbtVersion



WORKDIR /
ADD play /
RUN tree /
EXPOSE 9000
CMD sbt run
```

and my run command was

```
docker run -p 9000:9000 -t bee while bee is my image name
```

as you see the server is started properly.

please find bellow the attached picture to be more clearly [image]

here is the docker ps 
[image]

Comment: please put a `docker ps -a`

Comment: please look at my updated question

Comment: @BasilBattikhi are you using docker machine?

Comment: @lvthillo what do you mean i'm using windows at the docker console only. it just a terminal. thanks

Comment: Well on Windows you can use docker-machine but also a 'real' docker installation. Can you curl 127.0.0.1:9000 on the terminal? You are using docker machine I see.

Comment: @lvthillo as you see the terminal, the connection is being refused

Comment: and in your browser try: 192.168.99.100:9000?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

If you see your screenshot, it clear states the docker machine is located at `192.168.99.100`. So that is the address you need to use.

Open `http://192.168.99.100:9000` and it should work

Comment: how the docker took another ip

Comment: You are using `docker-machine` which use a virtual box VM in the background and that machine has this IP. For working on localhost you will need `Docker for Windows` which requires Windows 10 Professional or higher

Comment: Sounds Great, 
so far the request reached the docker server but there is a problem, 
im completely sure of the end point is GET and i sent a  request like this 

`http://192.168.99.100:9000/api/v1/US`

For request 'GET /api/v1/US' [Host not allowed: 192.168.99.100:9000]

Comment: Seems like you have some kind of whitelisting or something? Your node code should listen on `0.0.0.0` and don't have a host or ip restriction

Comment: Nope i have no restriction

Comment: @Turan maybe i have to have windows 8 or higher in order to use localhost because of hyper -v?

Comment: Localhost you can only use when you have hyper-v and using docker for windows. But docker-machine should also do the job. May be you are using API and pointing them to localhost?

Comment: No only the docker terminal